# Is it possible to load 3D model(for example vuforia unity or 3D Max) into Android studio project?

Tags: android, vuforia, 3d-modelling

I want to load 3D model into android studio and write the functionalities to it in java language.If anybody have an answer please do reply. I donot want to use .jpg or .png files.

Answer (score 0):

we can use 3DMax export the model to a .obj file,the file include the vertex of this model（you can try open it by a Editor）,then we can read the .obj file by java code

```
InputStream in=r.getAssets().open(fname);//fname is the .obj file name
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        String temps=null;

        //read .obj files
        while((temps=br.readLine())!=null) 
        {

            String[] tempsa=temps.split("[ ]+");
            if(tempsa[0].trim().equals("v"))//a "v" represent a Vertex
            {
                alv.add(Float.parseFloat(tempsa[1]));
                alv.add(Float.parseFloat(tempsa[2]));
                alv.add(Float.parseFloat(tempsa[3]));
            }

        } 

        //generate Vertex array 
        int size=alv.size();
        float[] vXYZ=new float[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            vXYZ[i]=alv.get(i);
        }
```

we can use the vXYZ rebuild 3D model by OpenGL

[the line is a .obj file export from 3Dmax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4mDz.jpg)